# JSON to yup schema (VeeValidate & Vue)

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, yup, vee-validate

I'm using Vue and VeeValidate.
I have this JSON :

```
{
    "98eca7d7-1f5c-4aa1-aff1-0b019841f08e": {
        "text": "Test"
    },
    "98eca7d7-1f5c-4aa1-aff1-0b019841f08f": {
        "text": "Test"
    }
}
```

The keys are identifiers.

And this schema :

```
import * as yup from "yup";

const schema = yup.object({
  [yup.string()]: yup.object({
    text: yup.string().required("Text is required"),
  }),
});

export default schema;
```

But when submitting the values, I never enter in my onSubmit function :

```
<script setup>
import { Form } from "vee-validate";
import ProfPunchlineTable from "./ProfPunchlineTable.vue";
import schema from "@/schema/punchlineProf.schema";

const onSubmit = (values) => {
  console.log(values);
};
</script>

<template>
  <Form @submit="onSubmit" :validation-schema="schema">
    <ProfPunchlineTable />
    <button type="submit">Valider</button>
  </Form>
</template>
```

The function work fine without the schema validation so I'm guessing my schema with yup is probably wrong. I would like to know what is the correct code for this kind of JSON.

Thanks for answer,